# Android ConnectException error - EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host) error

Tags: android, connection, google-cloud-functions, rx-java, retrofit2

I have been trying to request to a Google Cloud function and I have this error as a return:

> failed to connect to url/address (port X) from /Y (port Z) after 120000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

Details:

- It happens only when the device is using 3g connection (wifi works fine)
- It happens sometimes
- Only some devices display this behavior

Checking the cloud function, there is no error being logged there.

I am using Retrofit with RxJava2, these are the only pieces of code in Android that I thought that could be resulting in this kind of error.

I thought about it being a problem with the 3g provider, but I don't believe that's the case, as I created a hotspot with my cellphone, connected my computer and made the request using Postman and it worked fine.

Requesting through the browser also just worked fine.

Other than that, I'm pretty clueless, as it seems a completely specific and random error.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: were you able to find the issue?

Comment: @AniketShinde sadly I haven't...we dropped requesting the Google Cloud function for that endpoint because we didn't have time to keep looking, are you having the same problem? A friend of mine had a similar issue and he said it was because of IPv4 and IPv6 support for some devices, it was something related to that, but I don't know the specifics. I think he said his code switched between which IP to use. If you find anything useful, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This issue is specific to phone's network service. `EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)` essentially indicates that it was not able to build a route to reach the network. So 3g connection is failing at the point when you receive the error.

I see that IPv6 address in use. It will be useful to disable the IPv6 support on Android and see if you are still seeing the issue. This is available in the APN protocol settings in Mobile Networks > Advanced > Access Point.

Comment: I have a similar issue and found that the issue only comes for IPv6 addresses. The same Api connects fine on a web browser on IPv6 network